# Why the POST in firebug console is showing nothing and file is not getting uploaded in the following jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, file-upload

I've some Javascript code. I included the jQuery file **jquery-2.1.1.min.js** and converted the whole Javascript code to jQuery code but when I executed this code I'm not able to POST the file. Due to which I'm not able to upload the file to the server using PHP. In firebug console I'm always getting blank. Can someone please help me in correcting this issue?

Original Javascript code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Take or select photo(s) and upload</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function fileSelected() {
      var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;
      document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = "";
      for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++) {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];
        var fileSize = 0;
        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
          fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
        else
          fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

        document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += 'Name: ' + file.name + '<br>Size: ' + fileSize + '<br>Type: ' + file.type;
        document.getElementById('details').innerHTML += '<p>';
      }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
      var fd = new FormData();
      var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;
      for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++) {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];
        fd.append('myFile', file);
      }
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
      xhr.open("POST", "savetofile.php");
      xhr.send(fd);
    }

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
        document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
      }
    }

    function uploadComplete(evt) {
      /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
      alert(evt.target.responseText);
    }

    function uploadFailed(evt) {
      alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
    }

    function uploadCanceled(evt) {
      alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
    } 
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Upload.aspx">
      <div>
        <label for="fileToUpload">Take or select photo(s)</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
      </div> 
      <div id="details"></div>
      <div> 
        <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" /> 
      </div>
      <div id="progress"></div> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Converted above code to jQuery code as follows but getting blank in POST :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Take or select photo(s) and upload</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function fileSelected() {
      var count = $('#fileToUpload').get(0).files.length;//$('#fileToUpload').size() may also work
      $('#details').html("");
      for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++) {
        var file = $('#fileToUpload').get(0).files[index];//.get(0) gives you the js DOM object
        var fileSize = 0;
        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
          fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
        else
          fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
        $('#details').append('Name: ' + file.name + '<br>Size: ' + fileSize + '<br>Type: ' + file.type);
        $('#details').append('<p>');
      }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
      var fd = new FormData();
      var count = $('#fileToUpload').get(0).files.length;
      for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++) {
        var file = $('#fileToUpload').get(0).files[index];
        fd.append('myFile', file);
      }
      $.ajax({url:"savetofile.php", type:'POST', success:uploadComplete, error:uploadFailed});
      // abort is included in error, the second parameter passed to the error method would be statusText with value of abort in case of abort!
    }

    function uploadComplete(data) {
      /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
      alert(data);
    }

    function uploadFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      if(statusText==="abort") {
        alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.")
      } else {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
      }
    }
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Upload.aspx">
      <div>
        <label for="fileToUpload">Take or select photo(s)</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
      </div> 
      <div id="details"></div>
      <div> 
        <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" /> 
      </div>
      <div id="progress"></div> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

If you want I can give you the code of PHP file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing any data, this is what you're doing

```
$.ajax({
    url     : "savetofile.php", 
    type    : 'POST', 
    success : uploadComplete,  
    error   : uploadFailed
});
```

that, sends **nothing**, you have to actually add the data

```
$.ajax({
    url     : "savetofile.php", 
    type    : 'POST', 
    data    : fd,
    success : uploadComplete,  
    error   : uploadFailed
    cache   : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false
});
```